# Android Log Not Flushing Buffer on Crash

Tags: android, logging, android-ndk

I am developing for Android, and I have some calls to a native library.  It is currently crashing and so I'm adding Log calls, both to the Java classes and the c++ code.  The log statements are appearing correctly, using logcat in Android Studio, right up until the crash.  I can see the stacktrace and see functions that should have produced an output log message, but the messages are not there.  I think that the log messages are being buffered.

Is there any way to tell the Log system to flush?